# Insert two table with 1 caption

Tags: tables

[image]

How can I create these two tables with only 1 caption and 2 sub-caption like this figure in Latex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `\caption` instruction, two `tabular` environments, and `\multicolumn` instructions to provide headers for each of the two `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=bf,labelsep=newline,skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Market Data for the Zero Curve Construction}
{\centering (for December 18, 2007)\par}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\em(a) Libor Spot Rate Information}\\
\toprule
Term & Maturity & Days & Rate (\%)\\
\midrule
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{10}{c}@{}}
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\em(b) Eurodollar Futures Information}\\
\toprule
Contract & Price & Start Date & Days & End Date & Days & Days & Futures & Convexity & Forward \\
& & & ($T1$) & & ($T2$) & ($T2{-}T1$) & Rate (\%) & Adjustment & Rate (\%) \\
\midrule
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I adjust the margin of the second table without using the \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} for the whole document?

Comment: @Duy - Are you actually trying to replicate the table of which you posted a screenshot?

Comment: yes but I dont want to use the \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} since it may affect my other tables in the paper. I am now using the \hspace{2.5cm}\begin{table}.......\end{table}\hspace{2.5cm}. It works also

Comment: @Duy - As I said earlier, I have only rudimentary knowledge of what you're trying to do and what your document parameters are. So far, your descriptions unfortunately do not really clarify these issues. Please provide information about the width of your document's text block, the document font, and the main font size that's in use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one version utilizing `subcaption` (and `booktabs`). For more information on caption formatting have a look into the `caption` package's documentation.

[image: subcaption]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{General}
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Something}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule Quack? & Quack!\\\midrule
            Quack 1 & Quack 2\\
            Quack 3 & Quack 4\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\par
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Something else}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule Quack? & Quack!\\\midrule
            Quack 1 & Quack 2\\
            Quack 3 & Quack 4\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```